# jQuery error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dialog

I'm rewriting an existing application where I'm replacing a lot of Ajax control toolkit stuff with jQuery.
I'm running into a weird problem with the jQuery dialog:
The dialog opens fine, but when I click the close button and want to navigate away from the page, it throws me this error.

**Explanation of the code**

The dialog opens when clicking a button. An aspx page is loaded inside the dialog. This page also contains some jQuery stuff to display error messages and a dialog when the user enters false data.

This piece of code initializes and shows the first (outer) dialog:

```
function ShowDistributionDialog() {
        //Create the Add Distribution dialog
        $(dialogControl).dialog({
            title: 'Add/Edit Distributions',
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            width: 600,
            height: 475
        });

        //Load the Distribution page into the dialog
        $(dialogControl).load('./DistributionJQ.aspx?RID=' + rid + '&DistributionNr=' + distributionID);

        //Open the dialog
        $(dialogControl).dialog('open');
}
```

In the DistributionJQ.aspx page, there is a normal button to add the distribution. This triggers a postback so the data filled in this page can be saved to the database. I can open the dialog again without any issues.
When I click a link button (hosted in a user control somewhere else in the page) to return to the home page of the application, this error pops up.
When I click No in the Webpage Error dialog, the DistributionJQ.aspx (originally hosted in the dialog) page is displayed.

**Edit**
The mark up for the LinkButton looks like this:
    `<ASP:LINKBUTTON cssclass="Label hand" onclientclick="PleaseWait();" font-underline="True" font-size="10" runat="server" id="LinkButtonUserName" causesvalidation="false"></ASP:LINKBUTTON>`

I found out that the error occurs in the onclientclick method PleaseWait. So I took it out. When I click the linkbutton now, it shows me the DistributionJQ.aspx page. This all happens client side!! In the onclick method on the server is a response.redirect, but it does not get triggered!

I cannot explain what is going on here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In my humble opinion you have not provided enough info. If i am not mistaken the code you have provided isn't the one throwing the error.

Comment: You initialize dialog, then replace dialog's HTML code with something loaded from another page and then you're trying to open removed dialog, aren't you?

Comment: @user3558931 That's one of the points I'm not sure. Is it the dialog, the page loaded in the dialog or the page where the dialog is loaded that's throwing the error.

Comment: @Regent That's not 100% correct. I initialize the dialog, load contents of another page in it and then open the dialog. The dialog is never destroyed, just closed.

Comment: [jQuery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) replaces HTML contents of `$(dialogControl)`, so if `.dialog({ ... })` created some HTML elements inside `$(dialogControl)`, they all will be lost, and dialog will not work correctly.

Comment: @Regent That actually is just fine. When the dialog is closed the contents are not needed. The issue is when the dialog is closed and I click a LinkButton that resides in the master page, the error is shown.